# Credit Card Processing in Magento using authorize.net for different web sites

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

We are trying to use the same instance of Magento for 2 different domains.  We have a store that in Magento that is charging credit card using Authorize.net.  The customer will see that the charge is from company A.  We have a new project for a new website that we want to have the credit card charges on the customer statement show as Company B.  Our developer would like to use the same instance of Magento, but in order to have 2 different credit processors we have to have separate IP addresses for each Web site.

If you have 2 stores defined in the Magento can the Credit card processing be defined separately for each store using a different processor?

Comment: I would suspect Magneto is your best source of information here.

Comment: appreciate your quick response.  I already have posted question on the Magento users forum.  I am waiting to see if I get any responses.  I have gotten some data from the Authorize.net developer users forum.  I believe that the type of information I am working is the SOFT DESCRIPTIONS on credit card transactions.  Authorize.net does not support multiple SOFT DESRIPTIONS.